# Get Parse session id

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Alright, so while I can get the actual session token using

```
Parse.User.current().getSessionToken()
```

I haven't found a way to get the current session objectId however.

Is this possible using the javascript SDK?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Parse.Session.Current()](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Session.html#methods_current) method:

```
var current = Parse.Session.current().then(session => {
  //session:
    //createdAt: "2016-09-27T06:48:23.736Z"
    //createdWith: Object
    //expiresAt: Object
    //installationId: "72fdbb98-3a7d-7999-c2eb-afcb27902a2a"
    //objectId: "GnJWk0ruZ5"
    //restricted: false
    //sessionToken: "r:5b6ddd6c17989a8761e3d22458a1ea6a"
    //updatedAt: "2016-09-27T06:48:23.736Z"
    //user: Object
});
```

Hope it helps!